# Calculate mean date across years

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to calculate the mean date independent of year for each level of a factor.

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2013-2-15"), by = "day", length.out = 730))
DF$ID = rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), length.out = 730)
head(DF)

        Date  ID
1 2013-02-15 AAA
2 2013-02-16 BBB
3 2013-02-17 CCC
4 2013-02-18 AAA
5 2013-02-19 BBB
6 2013-02-20 CCC
```

With the data above and the code below, I can calculate the mean date for each factor, but this includes the year.

I want a mean month and day across years.  The preferred result would be a `POSIXct` time class formatted as month-day (eg. 12-31 for Dec 31st) representing the mean month and day across multiple years.

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 <- DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(
    Col = mean(Date, na.rm = T))
DF2
```

**Addition**
I am looking for the mean day of the year with a month and day component, for each factor level.   If the date represents, for example, the date an animal reproduced, I am not interested in the yearly differences between years, but instead want a single mean day.

I The end result would look like `DF2` but with the new value calculated as previously described (mean day of the year with a month day component.

Sorry this was not more clear.

Comment: I can think of several different ways to define this. The mean date across the whole time span perhaps (it would have a year, month, and day component). Or the mean day of the year (It would have a month and a day component. Or the mean month, and then the mean day.

Comment: Please show us the desired result.

Comment: I have added a few specifics per your request.

Comment: Well, with `yday` from data.table: `DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(myday = mean(yday(Date)))` I'm sure there's some analogue in the lubridate package. Convert back to "month and day" as you please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here's how to get a mean date column. I first extract the day of the year with `yday` from `POSIXlt`. I then calculate the `mean`. To get a date back, I have to add those days to an actual year, hence the creation of the `Year` object. As requested, I put the results in the same format as DF2 in your example.

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 <- DF %>%
mutate(Year=format(Date,"%Y"),
Date_day=as.POSIXlt(Date, origin = "1960-01-01")$yday)%>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(Col = mean(Date_day, na.rm = T),Mean_date=format(as.Date(paste0(Year,"-01-01"))+Col,"%m-%d"))%>%
select(Date,ID,Mean_date)
DF2
> DF2
Source: local data frame [730 x 3]
Groups: ID [3]

         Date    ID Mean_date
       (date) (chr)     (chr)
1  2013-02-15   AAA     07-02
2  2013-02-16   BBB     07-02
3  2013-02-17   CCC     07-01
4  2013-02-18   AAA     07-02
5  2013-02-19   BBB     07-02
6  2013-02-20   CCC     07-01
7  2013-02-21   AAA     07-02
8  2013-02-22   BBB     07-02
9  2013-02-23   CCC     07-01
10 2013-02-24   AAA     07-02
..        ...   ...       ...
```

Comment: Do you need to make a `Year` column; could you instead just paste on an arbitrary year, like `as.Date("1911-01-01")+Col` ? I guess the only difference would be inconsistencies within `ID` on account of leap years.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the mean of dates by using the mean function. However, note that the mean implementation (and result) **will be different depending on the data type**. For POSIXct, the mean will be calculated and return the date **and time** - think of taking the mean of a bunch of integers and you will likely get a float or numeric. For Date, it will essentially 'round' the date to the nearest date.

For example, I recently took a mean of dates. Look at the output when different data types are used.

```
> mean(as.Date(stationPointDf$knockInDate))
[1] "2018-06-04"
> mean(as.POSIXct(stationPointDf$knockInDate))
[1] "2018-06-03 21:19:21 CDT"
```

If I am looking for a mean Month and Day across years, I convert all the dates to have the current year using lubridate package.

```
library(lubridate)
year(myVectorOfDates) <- 2018
```

Then, I compute the mean and drop the year.